The Fourier transform of product of derivatives
I have the task to compute the Fourier transform of the product in matlab:
$$ \left( \frac{\partial u(t, x)}{\partial x} \right)^2 \left( \frac{\partial^2 u(t, x)}{\partial x^2 } \right)$$
I was trying to avoid the use  of convolution since whenever I tried using that, numerical errors affect the result. Thus, I was trying to find the better way to not use the matlab convolution function.
As a start, I re-express the above function in the form
$$\frac{1}{3}\frac{\partial } {\partial x} \bigg[\left(\frac{\partial u(t, x)}{\partial x} \right)^3 \bigg] $$
equalling the above term.
Yet, I got stuck with the derivative in the composition. Any idea how to continue or better way to compute the derivative in matlab efficiently?

Do you have $u(t,x)$ in closed form or is it a 2-dim array with discrete data points?

It is actually 2-dim array with discrete data points.

Here you'll find a MATLAB example how to get the derivatives: MSE_Q4935016
